# I'm wondering why its not showing loop result over and over in JavaScript click function if I wrap it in a tag

Tags: javascript, for-loop

In this example, I wanna show 3 checkbox items on click upon a button using for loop. But why its not showing loop result over and over everytime I click on event button? I mean, after getting all 3 items in result, it likes stop executing loop if I wrap in a tag like `<ul> ... </ul>` here.

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Front-End Development"> Front-End Development<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Back-End Development"> Back-End Development<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Design"> Design
</form>
<button id="show_check">Show</button>
<p>
    <strong id="selected_check"></strong>
</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("show_check").onclick = function() {
    var check = document.getElementsByName("interest");
    
    // wrapper
    document.getElementById("selected_check").innerHTML = "<ul>";

    for(var a = 0; a < check.length; a++) {
        if(check[a].checked) {
            document.getElementById("selected_check").innerHTML += "<li>" + check[a].value + "</li>";
        }
    }

    // wrapper
    document.getElementById("selected_check").innerHTML += "</ul>";
}
```

And if I removed `document.getElementById("selected_check").innerHTML = "<ul>"` from top and bottom of this loop, than its showing result over and over everytime I click on button. Even after getting all 3 results its still repeating.

But I'm wondering why its act like this and stop displaying repeated items if I wrap in a tag.

Comment: where is your `selected_check` element in the code you posted?

Comment: Edited post again. its just below button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use:

```
document.getElementById("selected_check").innerHTML =  "<ul>";
```

you're updating *all* of the HTML within your `selected_check` element to be a newly opened `<ul>` tag, meaning that any of the HTML contained within the `selected_check` element will be replaced with the opening `<ul>` tag. As a result, all of the `<li>` items added from the previous click are replaced.

If you remove this, then the rest of your code is using `.inneHTML +=`, which will add/append to the end of the HTML already contained within your `selected_check` element instead of replacing it.

---

As a side note, your current code is updating your DOM multiple times when you use `.innerHTML`, as well as querying the DOM every time you use `.getElementById()`. It's better to keep these DOM operations to a minimum by firstly building up your result, and then updating the DOM:

```js
document.getElementById("show_check").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const check = document.getElementsByName("interest");
  
  // Query the DOM element once and save it in a variable
  const selectedCheck = document.getElementById("selected_check");
  
  let listStr = "<ul>"; // create a string and build the HTML using that
  for (var a = 0; a < check.length; a++) {
    if (check[a].checked) {
      listStr += "<li>" + check[a].value + "</li>";
    }
  }
  // Once your string is built, update the DOM:
  selectedCheck.innerHTML = listStr;
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Front-End Development"> Front-End Development<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Back-End Development"> Back-End Development<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Design"> Design
</form>
<button id="show_check">Show</button>
<p>
  <strong id="selected_check"></strong>
</p>
```

Even with all that, `.innerHTML` is often best avoided, as there are quicker and safer ways of manipulating the DOM, such as creating your element first using `document.createElement()` and then updating the DOM:

```js
document.getElementById("show_check").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const check = document.getElementsByName("interest");
  
  // Query the DOM element once and save it in a variable
  const selectedCheck = document.getElementById("selected_check");
  
  // create a ul element object
  const ul = document.createElement("ul"); 
  
  for (var a = 0; a < check.length; a++) {
    if (check[a].checked) {
      // create a `<li>` object element and set its text to current value
      const li = document.createElement("li");
      li.textContent = check[a].value;
      ul.appendChild(li);
    }
  }
  // Once your ul element obejcts is built, update the DOM:
  selectedCheck.replaceChildren(ul);
  // for better browser support you can use `selectedCheck.innerHTML = ''; selectedCheck.appendChild(ul);`
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Front-End Development"> Front-End Development<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Back-End Development"> Back-End Development<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Design"> Design
</form>
<button id="show_check">Show</button>
<p>
  <strong id="selected_check"></strong>
</p>
```